# Block crawling of URLs with "tag" using robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I want to block robots from crawling URLs that contain the word "tag" on my website. Here are some example URLs:

1. `https://www.example.com/six-senses-fort-barwara-a-glimpse-into-the-spectacular-celebrity-destination-wedding-hotel/`

2. `https://www.example.com/tag/six-senses-fort-barwara/`

Where ever the "tag" comes in the URL, robots should be blocked from crawling any of the URLs in that subdirectory.

Comment: "Here are some example URLs" - Although, confusingly, the first URL does not contain "tag", so is presumably _not_ one of the URLs you would want to block? "Where ever the "tag" comes in the URL" - So, not just at the beginning of the URL-path (as in your example)? But presumably you only want to match `tag` when it occurs as a whole path segment, not literally anywhere in the URL-path? eg. Should `/this-url-is-tagged` be blocked or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can "block" the entire `/tag` directory:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /tag/
```

Also, consider adding the following to your "tag" pages:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
```

And make sure those pages are also excluded from your sitemap.